# android - How to display local calendar?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I'm using the new Calendar API and I want to create a local calendar in my application on which the user can add custom events related to the app .. So I've been able to create it through this code:

```
/** Creates the values the new calendar will have */
        private static ContentValues buildNewCalContentValues() {
            final ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME);
            cv.put(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
            cv.put(Calendars.NAME, CALENDAR_NAME);
            cv.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, CALENDAR_NAME);
            cv.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, 0xEA8561);
            // user can only read the calendar
            cv.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_READ);
            cv.put(Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_NAME);
            cv.put(Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
            cv.put(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
            return cv;
        }

        //Create and insert new calendar into android database

        public static void createCalendar(Context ctx) {
            ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
            final ContentValues cv = buildNewCalContentValues();
            Uri calUri = buildCalUri();
            // insert the calendar into the database
            cr.insert(calUri, cv);
        }
```

But the problem is I don't know how to display it and make the user interact with it.
Any help? Thanks in advance :)